# yesod devel fail when starting development server

Tags: haskell, yesod

I was starting to read about Yesod and I tried to install it on my Linux Mint Maya 64-bit machine. 
The haskell platform was already installed, I just installed the yesod-platform package with cabal install yesod-platform and all worked very well.

Next step was to call yesod init with respond to all the questions - the application name: test. The problems starts when I called yesod devel... here it is what I've got:

```
Yesod devel server. Press ENTER to quit
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring test-0.0.0...
Rebuilding application...
Building test-0.0.0...
Preprocessing library test-0.0.0...
Registering test-0.0.0...
Starting development server: runghc -package-confdist/package.conf.inplace devel.hs

devel.hs:2:1:
    Failed to load interface for `Application'
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
Exit code: ExitFailure 1
```

I'm a little bit lost with this issue - I made a lot of research related to it but I have no luck...

Can anyone help with this problem?

Here it is my ghc-pkg list:

```
    /var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d:
    Cabal-1.14.0
    GLUT-2.1.2.1
    HDBC-2.3.1.1
    HDBC-odbc-2.2.3.0
    HTTP-4000.2.2
    HUnit-1.2.4.2
    MonadCatchIO-mtl-0.3.0.4
    OpenGL-2.2.3.1
    QuickCheck-2.4.2
    SHA-1.5.0.0
    aeson-0.6.0.0
    ansi-terminal-0.5.5
    array-0.4.0.0
    asn1-data-0.6.1.3
    attoparsec-0.10.1.1
    attoparsec-conduit-0.2.0
    attoparsec-enumerator-0.3
    authenticate-1.0.0.1
    base-4.5.0.0
    base-unicode-symbols-0.2.2.3
    base64-bytestring-0.1.1.0
    bin-package-db-0.0.0.0
    binary-0.5.1.0
    blaze-builder-0.3.1.0
    blaze-builder-conduit-0.2.0
    blaze-html-0.4.3.1
    byteorder-1.0.3
    bytestring-0.9.2.1
    bytestring-lexing-0.4.0
    case-insensitive-0.4.0.1
    cereal-0.3.5.1
    certificate-1.1.0
    cgi-3001.1.8.2
    clientsession-0.7.4.1
    conduit-0.2.0
    containers-0.4.2.1
    convertible-1.0.11.0
    cookie-0.4.0
    cprng-aes-0.2.3
    crypto-api-0.9
    crypto-conduit-0.1.3.1
    crypto-pubkey-types-0.1.0
    cryptocipher-0.3.0
    cryptohash-0.7.4
    css-text-0.1.1
    data-default-0.3.0
    deepseq-1.3.0.0
    directory-1.1.0.2
    dlist-0.5
    email-validate-0.2.8
    entropy-0.2.1
    enumerator-0.4.18
    extensible-exceptions-0.1.1.4
    failure-0.2.0
    fast-logger-0.0.2
    fgl-5.4.2.4
    file-embed-0.0.4.1
    filepath-1.3.0.0
    (ghc-7.4.1)
    ghc-prim-0.2.0.0
    hamlet-0.10.8
    hashable-1.1.2.3
    haskell-src-1.0.1.5
    (haskell2010-1.1.0.1)
    (haskell98-2.0.0.1)
    hjsmin-0.0.15
    hoopl-3.8.7.3
    hpc-0.5.1.1
    html-1.0.1.2
    http-conduit-1.2.5
    http-date-0.0.2
    http-types-0.6.9
    integer-gmp-0.4.0.0
    language-javascript-0.4.10
    largeword-1.0.1
    lifted-base-0.1.0.3
    mime-mail-0.4.1.1
    monad-control-0.3.1
    mtl-2.0.1.0
    network-2.3.0.10
    old-locale-1.0.0.4
    old-time-1.1.0.0
    parallel-3.2.0.2
    parsec-3.1.2
    path-pieces-0.1.0
    persistent-0.8.0.1
    persistent-template-0.8.1.1
    pool-conduit-0.0.0.1
    pretty-1.1.1.0
    primitive-0.4.1
    process-1.1.0.1
    pureMD5-2.1.0.3
    pwstore-fast-2.2
    random-1.0.1.1
    ranges-0.2.4
    regex-base-0.93.2
    regex-compat-0.95.1
    regex-posix-0.95.1
    resource-pool-0.2.1.0
    rts-1.0
    safe-0.3.3
    semigroups-0.8
    shakespeare-0.10.3.1
    shakespeare-css-0.10.7
    shakespeare-i18n-0.0.1
    shakespeare-js-0.11.0.1
    shakespeare-text-0.10.5
    simple-sendfile-0.2.0
    skein-0.1.0.5
    socks-0.4.1
    stm-2.2.0.1
    syb-0.3.6
    system-filepath-0.4.6
    tagged-0.2.3.1
    tagsoup-0.12.6
    template-haskell-2.7.0.0
    text-0.11.1.13
    time-1.4
    tls-0.9.0
    tls-extra-0.4.3
    transformers-0.2.2.0
    transformers-base-0.4.1
    unix-2.5.1.0
    unix-compat-0.3.0.1
    unordered-containers-0.1.4.6
    utf8-light-0.4.0.1
    utf8-string-0.3.7
    vault-0.1.0.0
    vector-0.9.1
    wai-1.1.0.1
    wai-app-static-1.1.2
    wai-extra-1.1.0.1
    wai-logger-0.1.4
    warp-1.1.0.1
    xhtml-3000.2.0.5
    xml-conduit-0.5.3
    xml-types-0.3.1
    xss-sanitize-0.3.1
    yaml-0.5.2
    yesod-0.10.1.3
    yesod-auth-0.8.1.1
    yesod-core-0.10.2.1
    yesod-form-0.4.2
    yesod-json-0.3.1
    yesod-persistent-0.3.1
    yesod-routes-0.0.1
    yesod-static-0.10.1
    zlib-0.5.3.3
    zlib-bindings-0.0.3.2
    zlib-conduit-0.2.0

/home/ionica/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.4.1/package.conf.d:
    Cabal-1.16.0.1
    HDBC-2.3.1.1
    HDBC-odbc-2.3.1.0
    HDBC-sqlite3-2.3.3.0
    HaXml-1.23.3
    SHA-1.5.1
    aeson-0.6.0.2
    ansi-terminal-0.5.5
    asn1-data-0.7.1
    attoparsec-0.10.2.0
    attoparsec-conduit-0.5.0.2
    authenticate-1.3.1.1
    base-unicode-symbols-0.2.2.4
    base64-bytestring-1.0.0.0
    blaze-builder-0.3.1.0
    blaze-builder-conduit-0.5.0.1
    blaze-html-0.5.1.0
    blaze-markup-0.5.1.1
    byteorder-1.0.3
    cairo-0.12.3.1
    case-insensitive-0.4.0.3
    cereal-0.3.5.2
    certificate-1.2.8
    cipher-aes-0.1.2
    clientsession-0.8.0.1
    conduit-0.5.2.5
    conduit-0.5.2.6
    convertible-1.0.11.1
    cookie-0.4.0.1
    cpphs-1.14
    cprng-aes-0.2.4
    cpu-0.1.1
    crypto-api-0.10.2
    crypto-conduit-0.4.0.1
    crypto-pubkey-types-0.1.1
    cryptocipher-0.3.5
    cryptohash-0.7.5
    css-text-0.1.1
    data-default-0.5.0
    date-cache-0.3.0
    derive-2.5.11
    dlist-0.5
    email-validate-0.2.8
    entropy-0.2.1
    failure-0.2.0.1
    fast-logger-0.3.1
    file-embed-0.0.4.6
    filesystem-conduit-0.5.0.1
    ghc-paths-0.1.0.8
    gio-0.12.3
    glib-0.12.3.1
    gtk-0.12.3.1
    hamlet-1.1.1
    hashable-1.1.2.5
    haskell-src-exts-1.13.5
    hjsmin-0.1.3
    hspec-1.3.0.1
    hspec-expectations-0.3.0.2
    html-conduit-0.1.0.2
    http-conduit-1.6.1.2
    http-date-0.0.2
    http-types-0.7.3.0.1
    language-javascript-0.5.5
    largeword-1.0.3
    lifted-base-0.1.2
    lifted-base-0.2
    mime-mail-0.4.1.2
    mime-types-0.1.0.0
    monad-control-0.3.1.4
    monad-logger-0.2.1
    network-conduit-0.6.0
    network-conduit-0.6.1.1
    pango-0.12.3
    parallel-3.2.0.2
    parallel-3.2.0.3
    parallel-io-0.3.2.1
    path-pieces-0.1.2
    pem-0.1.1
    persistent-1.0.1.3
    persistent-sqlite-0.8.0
    persistent-sqlite-1.0.0
    persistent-template-1.0.0.2
    polyparse-1.8
    pool-conduit-0.1.0.3
    primitive-0.5
    primitive-0.5.0.1
    pureMD5-2.1.2.1
    pwstore-fast-2.3
    ranges-0.2.4
    resource-pool-0.2.1.1
    resourcet-0.4.0.1
    resourcet-0.4.0.2
    safe-0.3.3
    semigroups-0.8.4.1
    shakespeare-1.0.1.4
    shakespeare-css-1.0.1.5
    shakespeare-i18n-1.0.0.2
    shakespeare-js-1.0.0.6
    shakespeare-text-1.0.0.5
    silently-1.2.0.2
    simple-sendfile-0.2.8
    skein-0.1.0.9
    socks-0.4.2
    split-0.1.4.3
    stringsearch-0.3.6.4
    system-fileio-0.3.10
    system-filepath-0.4.7
    tagged-0.4.4
    tagsoup-0.12.8
    tagstream-conduit-0.5.3
    tar-0.3.2.0
    tar-0.4.0.1
    tls-0.9.11
    tls-extra-0.4.7
    transformers-base-0.4.1
    uniplate-1.6.7
    unix-compat-0.4.0.0
    unix-time-0.1.2
    unordered-containers-0.2.2.1
    utf8-string-0.3.7
    vault-0.2.0.1
    vector-0.10
    vector-0.10.0.1
    void-0.5.8
    wai-1.3.0.1
    wai-app-static-1.3.0.2
    wai-extra-1.3.0.3
    wai-logger-0.3.0
    wai-test-1.3.0
    warp-1.3.4.1
    xml-conduit-1.0.3.1
    xml-types-0.3.3
    xss-sanitize-0.3.2
    yaml-0.8.1
    yesod-1.1.2
    yesod-auth-1.1.1.2
    yesod-core-1.1.3.1
    yesod-default-0.6.1
    yesod-default-1.1.0.2
    yesod-form-1.1.3
    yesod-json-1.1.0
    yesod-persistent-1.1.0
    yesod-platform-1.1.4
    yesod-routes-1.1.0.1
    yesod-routes-1.1.0.2
    yesod-static-1.1.0.1
    yesod-test-0.3.0.1
    zlib-bindings-0.1.1.1
    zlib-conduit-0.5.0.1
```

Comment: I made a virtual machine with Linux Mint Maya - a fresh install - but with 32-bit architecture. All worked very well... the installation goes smoothly and the yesod devel hadn't any problem. However, devel.hs file it is quite different than the same file produced for 64-bit architecture... I start to think that I have to make a very carefully clean up on the 64-bit machine, in order to make things work! Am I right, or it is a problem with some incompatibilities related with the architecture? By the way, I do not have any broken dependencies...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too specific to apply to anyone else. The author also answered it by _reinstalled the environment and now it works_.

Answer (score 2):

After a complete clean up of the system - I mean uninstall haskell-platform, yesod-platform and delete files related to haskell, yesod and ghc - then a fresh install for haskell-platform + yesod-platform all goes splendid.